# How to repeat value not element in xslt

Tags: xslt

I am new to XSLT. Can anyone help me to get my desired output?

My code

```
 <xsl:for-each
                 select="/path-to-element-in-xpath">
                 <xsl:element name="element_name">
                       <xsl:attribute name="Type">text</xsl:attribute>
                       <xsl:attribute name="Value">
                      <xsl:value-of select="element_name/@displayValue"></xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:attribute>
                 </xsl:element>
          </xsl:for-each>
```

Actual output

```
    <element_name Type="text" Value="element_name_1"/>
        <element_name Type="text" Value="element_name_2"/>
        <element_name Type="text" Value="element_name_3"/>
        <element_name Type="text" Value="element_name_4"/>
        <element_name Type="text" Value="element_name_5"/>
```

Expected Output

```
<gl_coveragename Type="text" Value="element_name_1, element_name_2, element_name_3, element_name_4, element_name_5"/>
```

Addition : Need help to eliminate the duplicates in the value.

Comment: show us your XML and whatever xsl you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

You are adding new element for each loop instead you should add element only once as follows,

As we don't have any XML in the question, following is assumed to be one,

```
<data>
    <Element11 displayValue="First">
        <key>73004</key>
        <number>001001</number>
    </Element11>
    <Element11 displayValue="Second">
        <key>7300465</key>
        <number>002001</number>
    </Element11>
    <Element11 displayValue="Third">
        <key>730046</key>
        <number>003001</number>
    </Element11>
</data>
```

XSL template that should be added,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="http://locomotive/bypass/docx" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="data">
   <xsl:element name="element_name">
       <xsl:attribute name="Type">text</xsl:attribute>
       <xsl:attribute name="Value">       
        <xsl:for-each  select="Element11">
            <xsl:value-of select="@displayValue"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>                 
       </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:attribute> 
    </xsl:element>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```